When "users" tab is disabled in EventStore

Why Users and LogOut are  disabled in EventStore UI? I need them to change password.
Event Store 23.10.0.0

This might be helpful https://discuss.eventstore.com/t/admin-ui-buttons-disabled/2813/2

From the documentation:

When using the Insecure option for the server, all security is disabled. The Users menu item is also disabled in the Admin UI.

Basically, insecure mode means not only that you don't use TLS/HTTPS, but you disable all the security, including authorisation. That's why the Users tab doesn't make sense as you don't need user credentials when connecting from the client.

Can it be changed after installation? Is it possible to add secure mode after installation?

Of course, you need to remove the insecure option from the configuration, get a certificate for the cluster, and add the necessary certificate configuration to each cluster node.
